# ActiveAdmin and Warden route constraint

Tags: devise, activeadmin, warden

We recently updated to ActiveAdmin 1.1.0, on a site which maintains two distinct user models - Users and AdminUsers. ActiveAdmin authenticates AdminUsers, and the rest of the site authenticates Users. Both paths use Devise, like this:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: :practitioner_sessions, passwords: :practitioner_passwords}

  admin_devise_config = ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  admin_devise_config[:controllers][:sessions] = :sessions

  devise_for :admin_users, admin_devise_config
```

Now, I have a Rails engine (Resque::Server) mounted which I want to restrict to admins, using a routing constraint like this in `config/routes.rb`:

```
module RouteConstraint
  class Admin
    def self.matches?(request)
      request.env['warden'].user && request.env['warden'].user.admin?
    end
  end
end

  mount ResqueWeb::Engine, :at => "/resque", :constraints => RouteConstraint::Admin
```

This used to work. However, now when an AdminUser is logged in to ActiveAdmin, `request.env['warden'].user` returns `nil` and `request.env['warden'].authenticated?` returns `false`.

Where do I go to check if a user is authenticated with ActiveAdmin in this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["scopes" section of the Warden wiki](https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/wiki/Authenticated-session-data) gave me the clues I needed to rewrite two route constraints. Instead of querying the `user` method of the Warden object, I passed the relevant Devise scopes as arguments to the `authenticated?()` method. Remember that the Devise scopes can be found in `routes.rb`, e.g.:

```
devise_for :admin_users, admin_devise_config

devise_scope :admin_user do
  # some stuff
end
```

So then constraints can be written like this:

```
module RouteConstraint
  class SuperAdmin
    def self.matches?(request)
      warden = request.env['warden']
      warden.authenticated?(:admin_user)
    end
  end
end

module RouteConstraint
  class LoggedIn
    def self.matches?(request)
      warden = request.env['warden']
      warden.authenticated?(:user) || warden.authenticated?(:admin_user)
    end
  end
end
```

Then I was able to use the constraints in the same way as before:

```
  mount Resque::Server, :at => "/resque", :constraints => RouteConstraint::SuperAdmin
  mount JobState::Engine, :at => "/job_state", :constraints => RouteConstraint::LoggedIn
```